# function "boulders" in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function called boulders

```
void boulders (char landscapes[][L_WIDTH], int nrows);
```

basically, I'm supposed to populate an array with boulders and air where boulder is represented by 'o' and air is represented by '-'. it's supposed to be filled with random number of boulders, and finally it must follow rules of gravity.

for example:

```
--------------O---------
---O----------O-----O---
---OO------O--OO----OO--
---OO-----OOOOOO---OOO--
--OOOO---OOOOOOOO-OOOOO-
```

So far, I've got it to populate with random boulders and air, but I'm struggling on how to make it follow gravity rules.

Here is my code so far:

```
void boulders (char landscape[][L_WIDTH], int nrows) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, j;//populate with -
    for (i=0; i<nrows; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<L_WIDTH; j++) {
            landscape[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }

    int boulders;//random population of o
    for (i=0; i<nrows; i++) {
        boulders = rand() % L_WIDTH;
        for (j=0; j<boulders; j++) {
            landscape[rand()%(nrows)][rand()%L_WIDTH] = 'o';
        }
    }

    //follow gravitational rules
    for (i=nrows-1; i<0; i--) {
        for (j=0; j<L_WIDTH; j++) {
            if (landscape[i-1][j] == 'o') {
                landscape[i][j] = 'o';
            }
        }
    }

    //print
    for (i=0; i<nrows; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<L_WIDTH; j++) {
            printf("%c", landscape[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
main () {
    char landscape[6][L_WIDTH];
    boulders (landscape, 6);
}
```

Output:

[image]

L_WIDTH is defined to be 80 for reference

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: The question is pretty clear if you ask me. the boulders need to fall down as is clear by the example that was given.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if there is air under a boulder.

```
if (landscape[i-1][j] == 'o') {
     landscape[i][j] = 'o';
}
```

is not the code to do that.The condition must be, I am at a boulder position, and there is air in the position below it. Then and only then you make the position under the bolder which should be air, a bolder, and you make the bolder air. Net result, the bolder falls one position down.

The fact that your iteration starts 1 row above the bottom one and work your way up is correct. However this does not take into account that a boulder might have to drop multiple spaces if say there are 2 spaces of air underneeth it.
This can be solved in many ways. You might want to put a while condition in place.

```
 int boulderdropped = 1;
 while(boulderdropped==1){
     boulderdropped = 0;
     //do your iteration and if you detect air under a boulder 
     //set boulderdropped to 1 again.
 }
```

I am deliberately not giving you the solution. Just some hints.
So you can work out a solution of your own.
There are more efficient solutions than this one. Because actually boulders will  always grow from bottom to top. Count the number of boulders in a column is enough to get to the final layout quickly. Or better yet, you can even just randomize per column how many boulders there should be in that column.
This will yield the solution very quickly.
I went along with your code and gave some hints, but if you read the above text you can come up with better algorithms. Again I am deliberately not handing over a solution. You should be able to work it out yourself.

Answer (score -3):

```
//follow gravitational rules
for (i=0; i<nrows-1; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<L_WIDTH; j++) {
        if (landscape[i][j] == 'o'){
            int k;
            for(k = i+1; k < nrows; ++k){
                if(landscape[k][j] == '-') {
                    landscape[k][j] = 'o';
                    landscape[i][j] = '-';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//follow gravitational rules
for (i=nrows-1; i>=0; i--) {
    for (j=0; j<L_WIDTH; j++) {
        if (landscape[i][j] == '-'){
            int k;
            for(k = i-1; k >= 0; --k){
                if(landscape[k][j] == 'o') {
                    landscape[k][j] = '-';
                    landscape[i][j] = 'o';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What am I looking at? Could you explain the code blocks?